# Keeping crosshairs & GUI onscreen - SFML

Tags: gui, sfml

I read [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15380/how-to-keep-a-gui-on-screen-without-moving-or-resizing-it-according-to-camera-mo), but didn't understand the implementation suggestions with SFML on C#.

For example, right now I'm just trying to make sure that the mouse crosshairs stay onscreen constantly. I tried using this code:

```
        View lastView = this._mainWindow.GetView();
        this._mainWindow.SetView(this._mainWindow.DefaultView);
        this._mainWindow.Draw(crosshair);
        this._mainWindow.SetView(lastView);
```

After drawing all other sprites and before call this._mainWindow.display(), when beforehand I set crosshair.Position based on its position relative to the window, not the view. 
This just keeps the screen locked and prevents screen scrolling. Any suggestions?